# PDF iframe in UWP application

Tags: iframe, uwp

We have web application, it contains iframe with src attribute linking some pdf resource. In browsers (Edge, Chrome, Opera) user can see pdf in this iframe.

But now we createed UWP application showing the same html pages. When user open the page with this iframe, iframe is empty and the pdf is automaticaly opened in the browser window.

How to enable support for pdf in iframe in UWP application?

Comment: You could convert it to an image using `GhostScript`, you can embed chrome into the application and display it using that. Lots of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to use WebView to show a web page. The web page has a `<iframe>` html tag, the iframe's src is a online pdf file. For the UWP built-in [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#remarks) control, it doesn't support pdf file.

So, if you want to render pdf in UWP, you could use [Windows.Data.Pdf classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Pdf).

In addition, if you say you have to use WebView to show pdf file, you could try to find some JavaScript ways to render the pdf file on web page and then show it in WebView.